# what happens to an electrons orbital when it absorbs a photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

so I just learned about orbitals and hybridization theory through youtube and I have one question.

if I have a hydrogen with one electron, the electron is in a 1s orbital, but then if that electron absorbs a photon and it goes up an orbital will it only increase to other 's' orbitals or would it, for example, go to a 'p' orbital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are selection rules. $\Delta l=\pm 1$ and $\Delta m_l=\pm 1,0$. Hence electron can go to the p orbital but it cannot go to the s orbital. Because $s$ orbital would correspond to the $l=0$. But the electron was in already $l=0$. So it has to go $l=1$ orbital to satify the selection rule condition.

So it cannot go $2s$ but it has to go $2p$.

Comment: so once it's at the 2p orbital I can't go to '3s'? and would the selection rules apply for higher orbital types like if the one electron started in an 'f' orbital (somehow)

Comment: If its on 2p it can go to 3s. At $2p$, $l=1$ and at $3s$, $l=0$ so change in the $l$ is 1, hence we can pass. Yes you can apply it to any orbital it doesnt matter. But if its on $f$ it cannot go $s$ or $p$ its not allowed. But these are true for one photon emission/absorption case.

Comment: can you edit your comment there is some error. Its hard to understand

Comment: also, the confusion I had came from me thinking that by just increasing the energy of the electron it wouldn't change the way the electron makes the orbital (because the orbital is just the volume the electron takes 90% of the time) by increasing the energy it takes the same average path just with more momentum so it has more centripetal force. so, it would go s1, s2, s3 and so on

Comment: as I understand it: l is the orbital type (the letter) and it can only change by 1 each time a photon is absorbed or emitted. when 'l' was zero you have to go up to l = 1 as you can't go lower than the 1s orbital

Comment: I did not understand the s1,s2,s3 thing. Well yes the reason is photon has also angular momentum. So to conserve angular momentum., the electron's angular momentum should change.

Comment: well  I thought that the electron had to stay in the s orbital which has energy levels 1, 2, 3.. and that you only get a change in orbitals 'shape' when you have an increase of electrons eg. S, p, d as shown on the [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj125isgYbgAhVRbysKHZqiBAoQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchem.libretexts.org%2FUnder_Construction%2FEssential_Chemistry_(Curriki)%2FUnit_1%253A_Atomic_and_Molecular_Structure%2F1.4%253A_Electron_Configuration_and_Orbital_Diagrams&psig=AOvVaw1TjQHVD6P1KLgpiq8P6n47&ust=1548405290364119)

Comment: I see your point. But that's something else. We are not talking about increasing the electron number. We are talking about exciting an electron. In this case, as I explained before, the photon has angular momentum, the electron has angular momentum, Hence to conserve total angular momentum, electron angular momentum (l) must change.

Comment: If you hit electron with a photon, the electron cannot have the same angular momentum at the end.

Comment: ok this is a bit out of my level but I think I've got what your saying

Comment: @Ryan An electron in any s orbital has zero orbital angular momentum (of course, it always has intrinsic angular momentum, aka spin).